# Error when importing maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring boot application and i am not able to import the security test above .

I have this dependency . the word with red line in import is "test"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This looks like more of a Maven problem. Hovering the red line will give you *an exact error message*, and we'll probably need more than just a couple of lines extracted from the middle of your POM.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol test @chrylis 4 hours thats what it shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error as Maven trying to fetch a dependency that has no `LATEST` or `RELEASE` version; you have to define a very specific version. This should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)

> By the way, I tried this on my project and it works for me.